# wordnet database editor

Tags: nlp, wordnet

I downloaded the latest Wordnet version for Windows (2.1) and I want to establish a link between two verb synsets. Is there a wordnet synset editor out there I can use for this? They published documentation that describes their file structure, but writing an editor of my own is not something I want to be dedicating time towards.

Thanks

mj

Answer (score 1):

[DEBVisDic](http://nlp.fi.muni.cz/projects/deb2/doc.php) is probably what you are looking for. This is client-server application, so if you want to install local server it may be little complicated (debian-based distro is prerequisite for example).

Comment: I was looking for something that could (on Windows) directly edit the database w/out the back end web server. A command line app would suffice. Thanks anyways. -mj